# authorize.net subscription reneval reminders

Tags: email, authorize.net, subscriptions, reminders

i have a site where users registered for a 1 year period using as authorize.net as the paymnent gateway.i would like to know if the subscription is up for renewal does authorize.net send reminders as the expiry date of 1 year approaches?

Answer (score 1):

No, they do not. This is something you need to keep track of on your end.